# Octopus deployment, unable to read package format error in package

Tags: c#, windows, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I have made small changes in my MVC project, added new page and I have started to have problems with Octopus deployment. I can't find where is problem. Package is created in TeamCity, this is working on Windows.

```
Unable to download package: 
Unable to read package from path 'Web.Position.1.1.1819.nupkg'.
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to read package from path 'Web.Position.1.1.1819.nupkg'. ---> System.IO.FileFormatException: Format error in package.
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetParts()
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
   at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsureManifest()
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.OpenPackage(String path)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.OpenPackage(String path)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.GetPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String path)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.<>c__DisplayClass13.<FindPackage>b__f(String path)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
   at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)
   at NuGet.DataServicePackage.EnsurePackage(IPackageCacheRepository cacheRepository)
   at NuGet.DataServicePackage.GetStream()
   at NuGet.FileSystemExtensions.AddFileWithCheck(IFileSystem fileSystem, String path, Func`1 streamFactory)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.AddPackage(IPackage package)
   at Octopus.Core.Packages.PackageDownloader.AttemptToFindAndDownloadPackage(Int32 attempt, PackageIdentifier packageIdentifier, IFeed feed, String cacheDirectory, IPackage& downloadedPackage, String& path) in Y:\work\refs\tags\3.3.14\source\Octopus.Core\Packages\PackageDownloader.cs:line 155
   at Octopus.Core.Packages.PackageDownloader.AttemptToDownload(PackageIdentifier packageIdentifier, IFeed feed) in Y:\work\refs\tags\3.3.14\source\Octopus.Core\Packages\PackageDownloader.cs:line 101
Octopus.Server version 3.3.14 (3.3.14+Branch.master.Sha.94cbad9d1e5d9a9515a90f390455374b9fbe30f8)
```

I download this package locally and check content via 'Nuget NuPkg Viewer', all looks correct. I compared with previous package which is ok, I couldn't find any differences.

I don't know what I can check to find where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

After few hours I found my problem. During development I have renamed one of my folder from projectmanager to projectManager (changed m to capital letter) and afer this I had issue. When I downloaded nuget package and changed extension to .zip and tried to unzip I have warnings that same files are already unziped and if I want to override this. When I open this zip file I noticed that in folder projectManager are duplicated files with the same name. So looks that build server created in package two folders projectmanager and projectManager and during unpacking was problem with duplicated files.